# Groovy assert fail

Tags: groovy

I learn Groovy language. I use Groovy SDK 3.0.6 on Windows 10 x64. I read the reference document at http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_groovydoc_comment . File `Hello.groovy`

```
// đây là ghi chú.
println("Hello Hanoi");

/*
Đây là ghi chú nhiều dòng.
Cần thêm 1 dòng nữa.
 */

/**@
 * Nhân viên.
 */
class Employee{

    /**@
     * In ra câu thông báo có tham số đầu vào.
     *
     * @param text
     * @return
     */
    String hello(String employeeName){
        "Xin chao, ${employeeName}";
    }
}

assert Employee.groovydoc.content.contains('Nhân')
```

Run

```
groovy Hello.groovy
```

I seen error

```
D:\github>groovy Hello.groovy
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Hello Hanoi
Caught: Assertion failed:

assert Employee.groovydoc.content.contains('Nhân')
                |         |       |
                |         ''      false
                groovy.lang.groovydoc.Groovydoc$1@3688eb5b (toString() == "")

Assertion failed:

assert Employee.groovydoc.content.contains('Nhân')
                |         |       |
                |         ''      false
                groovy.lang.groovydoc.Groovydoc$1@3688eb5b (toString() == "")

        at Hello.run(Hello.groovy:25)

D:\github>
```

- Second time

File `Employee2.groovy`

```
/**@
 * Some class groovydoc for Foo
 */
class Foo {
    /**@
     * Some method groovydoc for bar
     */
    void bar() {
    }
}

assert Foo.class.groovydoc.content.contains('Some class groovydoc for Foo')
assert Foo.class.getMethod('bar', new Class[0]).groovydoc.content.contains('Some method groovydoc for bar')
```

[image]

How to fix it? How to run it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to miss, but from [the documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_groovydoc_comment), the following flag is required in order to have Groovydoc at run-time:

```
groovy -Dgroovy.attach.runtime.groovydoc=true Employee2.groovy
```